# Lifetime parameters for an enum within a struct

Tags: struct, enums, rust, lifetime

I don't understand why I get an error with this type of structure

```rust
enum Cell <'a> {
    Str(&'a str),
    Double(&'a f32),
}

struct MyCellRep<'a> {
    value: &'a Cell,
    ptr: *const u8,
}

impl MyCellRep{
    fn new_from_str(s: &str) {
        MyCellRep { value: Cell::Str(&s), ptr: new_sCell(CString::new(&s)) }
    }

    fn new_from_double(d: &f32) {
        MyCellRep { value: Cell::Double(&d), ptr: new_dCell(&d) }
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
14:22 error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]
src\lib.rs:14     value : & 'a Cell ,
```

So I tried also

```rust
struct MyCellRep<'a> {
    value: &'a Cell + 'a,
    ptr: *const u8,
}
```

but got

```
14:22 error: expected a path on the left-hand side of `+`, not `&'a Cell`
```

I presume the `Cell` should have the lifetime of `MyCellRep`, and `Cell::Str` and `Cell::Double` should at least have the lifetime of the `Cell`.

Eventually what I was to be able to do is just say

```rust
let x = MyCellRef::new_from_str("foo");
let y = MyCellRef::new_from_double(123.0);
```

**Update**
I would like to add, by changing the Cell definition, the rest of the code should also change to the following for anyone else searching answers.

```rust
pub enum Cell<'a> {
    Str(&'a str),
    Double(&'a f32),
}


struct MyCellRep<'a> {
    value: Cell<'a>, // Ref to enum 
    ptr: *const u8, // Pointer to c struct
}

impl<'a>  MyCellRep<'a> {
    fn from_str(s: &'a str) -> DbaxCell<'a> {
        MyCellRep { value: Cell::Str(&s) , ptr: unsafe { new_sCell(CString::new(s).unwrap()) } }
    }

    fn from_double(d: &'a f32) -> DbaxCell {
        MyCellRep{ value: Cell::Double(&d) , ptr: unsafe { new_dCell(*d) } }
    }
}
```

What I love about Rust is just like OCaml, if it compiles it works :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You (understandably) misinterpreted the error message:

```
14:22 error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]
src\lib.rs:14     value : & 'a Cell ,
```

You thought "But I provided the lifetime parameter! It is `'a`!" However, the compiler is trying to tell you that you did not provide a lifetime parameter *for* Cell (not the reference to it):

```
Cell<'a>
```

Comment: (Answer to your deleted comment): I would try replacing `value: &'a Cell` by `value: Cell<'a>` in the struct, but I'm not 100% certain that's what you want. If it compiles, it's probably what you want, though. More complex (but more powerful) would be `value: &'a Cell<'b>` where `'b` is declared in the struct params: `MyCellRep<'a, 'b>`

Comment: Yes I did you first change and ended up with Cell<'a>, and then, yes the 2nd MyCellRep<'a,'b> intuitively became what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

[mdup is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30786105/155423), but the **error message helps you**. For some reason, many people ignore the part of the error message that *points to the error*:

```
<anon>:7:16: 7:20 error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]
<anon>:7     value: &'a Cell,
                        ^~~~
```

Sometimes, I want to submit a PR that makes the `^~~~~` blink in the terminal ^_^.

Comment: To be fair, the arrow tip points to the left of the type, no surprise one wants to correct the reference instead of the (unseen) type parameter :)

Comment: @mdup but the arrow *highlights* the problem in question, not just a single point. That is, the `^` and the `~` are both important. I really want to figure out how to improve this UX.

Comment: Agreed. Maybe the part designated by `^~~~` could be also highlighted by changing the term background color.